# Why would an OpenCV program capturing video frames freeze after a few seconds?

Tags: c++, opencv, raspberry-pi

I successfully installed [cvBlob](http://code.google.com/p/cvblob/) on my Raspberry Pi and compiled `red_object_tracking.cpp` on it using the provided `Makefile` (code located [here](http://cvblob.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/samples/))

When I execute `./red_object_tracking` I see the GUI pop up and I see the first few video frames my webcam captures, however, after 5 seconds it freezes and the frames don't update anymore. The program doesn't crash because when I execute "top" I can see it is using 93% of CPU and like 30% of memory.

When I tried building and executing the same program on my mac it worked perfectly (i.e. the frames were updating and when I placed my red pen in front of the camera it correctly boxed only the red parts within a rectangle.

Does anyone know why it's not working properly on my pi?
I'm running the latest version of Raspbian Wheezy and using Open CV 2.3.1.

Should I try overclocking the my pi's CPU or memory?

Should I run a different operating system on the pi instead of Raspbian Wheezy?

Would appreciate all / any input

Comment: browse through raspberry pi forum...frame rate of webcam with raspberry pi is low...

Comment: OpenCV is curently on version 2.4.2. I suggest you upgrade to this version and try again.

Comment: A wild guess: increase the value passed to `cvWaitKey(10)`. Right now this means that the loop is only sleeping 10ms before grabbing the next frame. This might be too fast for your platform. Make sure you put debugs (`printf()` calls) all over the loop to figure out where it is blocking.

Comment: You can also run it with strace to see what's happening.

Comment: http://help.simplecv.org/question/1174/getimage-has-stale-frames/ similar issues of frames here.

Answer (score 0):

There are some [known problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14736270/raspberry-pi-usb-redirect-issue/14866397#14866397) with USB, which are likely affecting your web camera (connected via USB).  There are still some [outstanding issues related to cameras](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=23544&start=225), although others sound to be working.  Try running rpi-update and see if that addresses your issues.