# Raspberry Pi becomes unresponsive when running OpenCV

Tags: image-processing, opencv, webcam, raspberry-pi

I have successfully installed OpenCV on my Raspberry Pi and have been fooling around with some simple webcam streaming, live canny-edge detection, and so forth, all using basic C and C++ code.

However, I'm running into problems with the two webcams I'm using. The first, a really basic, cheap Logitech I had sitting around, works fine, but the image quality leaves a LOT to be desired. But when I switch to my Logitech 510c camera, the image is much better, but the Pi freezes.

Rather, the streaming program continues to run fine, but I can't exit the program - the Raspberry Pi stops responding to the keyboard and the mouse, and the only way to quit is to unplug the Raspberry Pi. Here's an example of some of the code:

```
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

  int c, i, j;

  //Capture frame from camera
  CvCapture* capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(CV_CAP_ANY);
  if(!capture){
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: capture is NULL \n");
    getchar();
    return -1;
  }

  //Set resolution of capture
  cvSetCaptureProperty(capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 256);
  cvSetCaptureProperty(capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 192);

  //Create window for display
  cvNamedWindow("canny");

  while(true){

    //Find/mark edges using canny
    IplImage* frame = cvQueryFrame(capture);
    IplImage* grey = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(frame), 8, 1);
    cvCvtColor(frame, grey, CV_RGB2GRAY);
    IplImage* frame2 = cvCreateImage(cvSize(grey->width+6, grey->height+6), grey->depth, grey->nChannels);

    CvPoint offset = cvPoint(3,3);
    cvCopyMakeBorder(grey, frame2, offset, IPL_BORDER_REPLICATE, cvScalarAll(0));
    IplImage* edges = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(frame2), IPL_DEPTH_8U, frame2->nChannels);
    cvCanny(frame2, edges, 4900, 39200, 7);

    cvShowImage("canny", edges);

    //Wait for a keypress
    int c = cvWaitKey(10);
    if (c!=-1)
        break;
  } //End while

  cvReleaseCapture (&capture);
  cvDestroyWindow("canny");
  return 0;
} //End main
```

Is there a problem with my code? Do I need to use a different webcam? I've overclocked the Raspberry Pi; can it simply not handle the stream with a better-quality camera?

Comment: RPi has it's own SE site ==> http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks- I had no idea. I'll ask over there. Shall I remove it here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are [known issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12748115/why-would-an-opencv-program-capturing-video-frames-freeze-after-a-few-seconds/15595962#15595962) with video cameras on Raspberry Pi, boiling down to the USB handling. You can try upgrading to the latest kernel, although most the fixes so far have not affected cameras.

Comment: Thanks for this. I've upgraded, with no effect, so I guess I'll stick to lower quality video for now.

Answer (score 1):

I think the Raspberry Pi limits its current up to 700 mA on its USB ports, so if your camera works with 700 mA or less, it should work fine. If not, you should buy a powered USB hub. I have an Logitech C170 camera that has a 700 mA current rating, and it works fine without a powered USB hub.

I would like to know how did you install OpenCV on your Raspberry Pi so you can use it with C/C++, and if you use an IDE to make your programs, I also would like to know how do you do it. I have searched for a tutorial of how to do this, but I only have found tutorials of how to install OpenCV for using it with Python. I need to use C/C++, because I have tried Python, and I think it is really slow for image processing. I'm using the Debian 6.0 (Squeeze) OS.

Answer (score 0):

The reason may be that your cameras draw more current, leaving the Raspberry Pi unresponsive. Check the current rating of your camera and try having a camera with a current rating of not greater than 100 mA.

Comment: or attach an active owered usb hub ;)