# Raspberry Pi usb redirect issue

Tags: remote-desktop, raspberry-pi, thin-client

Okay I am going to try and be as discriptive as possible here to get this problem solved. I work at a company that makes BIG gear boxes and we have computers that run our Mills/Laths. These computers are currently FIT-PCs running XP. These computers are used to control the laths/mills via a usb to serial converter (PL2303_Prolific usb to serial converter). When it is plugged into an xp machine it is recognized as a com port. SO these machines are very old and are fail left and right, I intend to replace them with a raspberry pi running xfreerdp but I can't seem to get the usb serial device to be redirected to the virtual machine it is remoting into. Has anyone ran into this/know a fix for it? Please ask me questions if you are unsure of something because I am completely stuck here. TLDR Using raspberry pis as thin clients need to push a usb 2 serial cable through to the virtual xp machine

Comment: I've no experience with them, but besides the Raspberry Pi there's also [BeagleBone](http://beagleboard.org/bone).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there are known issues with USB on Raspberry Pi. They're aware of the issue and working on it, but it is as of yet unresolved.

The [USB Redux thread](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?t=23544) was created to capture the state of the work as well as the current list of work-arounds.  The [USB/serial converters are broken](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=16280&start=100) is a related thread.

There is hope, however.  First, they are working actively to fix it, so I suspect it's just a matter of time.  Second, there are a few things you can try.

- There's a config file in
  /boot/cmdline.txt where you can try adding a few entries. One that appears quite effective is dwc_otg.speed=1 and dwc_otg.fiq_fix_enable=1 (but they didn't help me).  See [this page](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=16280&start=50) for some examples.
- Update the kernel (search for [rpi-update](https://github.com/Hexxeh/rpi-update)) to at least #348 (use uname -a to determine the kernel level)

Good luck.

Update (Mar 13 2013).  There [appears to be a fix](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=23544&start=200) for the majority of USB issues as of kernel #389.  Use [rpi-update](https://github.com/Hexxeh/rpi-update) to update.