# pyusb: function works well once, the second time fails

Tags: python, usb, raspberry-pi, pyusb, raspbian

I have a raspberry pi (I'm using linux) and a device that measures some values.

I have a python server and when a client sends a  "I want the values" command, I ask the device some values. This is the function for my device:

```
def usbDevice:
      dev = usb.core.find(idVendor=0xXXXX, idProduct=0xXXXX)
      if dev is None:
         return 'Not found'
      dev.set_configuration()
      dev.write(1, '\x05', 0) # ask for the values
      time.sleep(2)
      ret = dev.read(0x81,2048 , 0,1200) # endpoint, siz, interf, timeout ->meas. vals
      print ret
      return ret
```

When I start the communication it always goes well (both ways, I send the command and I get the 
proper response ...).However, the second time I try it (no matter if I wait too long or not) I'm getting no response from the device. I know I can send the request (I used a print "step XX" to see where it is failing), but I get no answer... I am usually getting a timeout exception, but sometimes getting a "resource busy" exception.

Should I close the usb communication after using it the first time? How? Despite, I'm always compiling with sudo permissions, I created a .rules file, so I think there's not the problem.

Apart from this, I would really like to know if something's wrong with this way to establish the USB communication as I used something similar in the past. ( and I'm not good with python...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you provide additional information such as the linux distribution and kernel number e.g.

```
 uname -a
```

There are [known USB issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14736270/raspberry-pi-usb-redirect-issue/14866397#14866397).  The good news is that a [recent fix](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=23544&start=200) may have resolved them.  Basically, use [rpi-update](https://github.com/Hexxeh/rpi-update) and it should update the kernel (you want at least #389).

Comment: I think it might be a hardware problem I had with my raspberry. As soon as I get another one I can answer you being 100% sure... anyway, what you suggest seems the solution,As said before THANKS for the info!!

Comment: Yes it was that. Working well with the last Raspbian but not with my old one. Thanks again!!